# How to render a terrain using height maps and getting basic collision detection on top of the terrain and camera (moving on the terrain)

Tags: opengl

I have loaded a .RAW file into a 2x2 array in my class. The way I am rendering it works fine but I am struggling to get the camera to move on top of the terrain. The terrain renders from 0,0,0 (x,y,z) as that is where I put my camera. My camera class allows to the "camera" to move through the scene.

I want to be able to "walk" on top of the terrain with some basic collision detection (if possible).
Any tips on where to go for this or any tips?

Comment: the Game Dev SE site might be able to provide you with some good links. You could ask the moderators to migrate this question there: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If one assumes that (0, 1, 0) is the vector that poins to the sky, a collision occurs, when the terrains height at the cameras X and Z coordinates is greater or equal to the Y coordinate of the camera. The next thing is, the camera needs [gravity](http://www.rodedev.com/tutorials/gamephysics/) to stick at the ground.